# How to get result of function variable of pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I created code to get the URL parameter. I would just like to have a unique task for this function, not the implementation of the result, that the responsibilities will belong to other future functions.

I searched for various internet search combinations, like "get javascript return", "get function result", or something. But without success! In the end, it has to make the function have only one task in order to be manipulated by other functions.

```
function getURL(){

        var getURLs = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');

        var getURLArray = {};

        for(var i=0; i<getURLs.length; i++) {

            var getURL = getURLs[i].split('=');

            getURLArray[getURL[0]] = getURL[1];
        }

        action = getURL[0]  ;
    }
```

The purpose of the function is to just get the value of the parameter, without having to use global variable or Storage API (localStorage or sessionStorage).

Comment: You'll want to `return action` at the end of that `function`.

Comment: why the loop if you only ever want `getURL[0]` - P.S. dont' declare a variable inside a for loop that you want to use outside of it - while this works with `var`, it's not good practice

Comment: It's like return = myResult; ? And how to share this result for another funcion without global variabe or Storage?

Comment: `return = myResult;` - this isn't VB6 ... it's like `return xxxx` where `xxxx` is the value you want to return, as a literal or a variable

Comment: `how to share this result` - huh? you call the function, you get the result

Comment: And how to get the "return" for another functions?

Comment: you call the function to get the result ... you always have to call a function to get the result of calling a function, at least once! getUrl does nothing until you call `getUrl()` - note your `getURL` function is ... a global variable - so you're already "breaking" your self imposed restrictions

Comment: function first(){
// code
return 'result';
}
function second(){

console.log(return); // <----- how to get the return of first function?

Comment: function second can call function first ... you're just showing function definitions, never how you want to use them, so it's really hard to know what you want

Comment: I want make a result with a function, but not have a implamentation with a result.

Comment: A simple reusable result of function. A simple wish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `return` keyword:

```
function getURL(){

        var getURLs = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');

        var getURLArray = {};

        for(var i=0; i<getURLs.length; i++) {

            var getURL = getURLs[i].split('=');

            getURLArray[getURL[0]] = getURL[1];
        }

        action = getURL[0]  ;

        return action;
    }
```

To use the result in another place in your code you simple assign the result to a variable or just use it directly:

```
var myVar = getURL(); // You can use 'let' or 'const' to declare local variables.

// or

console.log(getURL());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Reason for downvote? If I missunderstood the question please let me know.

Comment: I didn't downgrade, but I have a question: Is using global the only way to get reusable function results in other functions? It is a sincere question!

Comment: @SérgioLima You can also use the result directly, like for example as an argument for another function call. I have edited my answer to include an example of using the returned value directly in `console.log()`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @SérgioLima If you want to store the value in a local variable, inside another function for example, you can use the `let` or `const` keyword instead of `var` when you declare the variable. https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_let.asp

Comment: I did it that way
function action($value){
   console.log($value);
  }
function foo(){
// code
return result;
action(result);
}

So....yes! You did. But complete the answer with this last example, please, for a future people. Thanks!